# Android: Add multiple views to ListView App Widget

Tags: android, listview, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-appwidget, stackview

I am trying to create a homescreen widget using the 3.1 SDK. I followed the [StackWidget](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/StackWidget/index.html) tutorial. and changed the `StackView` to `ListView`.
I want to add an image and text to each row in my list, and these are loaded at runtime.

I use this code in my `WidgetProvider.java` class

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mWidgetItems.get(position).getImage());

    RemoteViews image = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);      
    image.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget_image, bitmap );

    RemoteViews text = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item); 
    text.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_text, mWidgetItems.get(position).getText());

    RemoteViews layout = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putInt(StackWidgetProvider.EXTRA_ITEM, position);
    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
    fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);

    layout.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_item, fillInIntent);

    return layout;
}
```

All of this works correctly when I use `StackView`, but changing to `ListView` messes up everything. The result is this

[image]

Only one view can be returned. So, if I add the following code, this problem occurs, if I don't add it, then the content of the list is empty.

```
layout.addView(R.id.widget_item, image);
layout.addView(R.id.widget_item, text);
```

How else do I add multple views to a widget?
Why does this work for StackView but not ListView? 
and how do I rectify this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

widget_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget_item"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center_vertical">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/widget_image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widget_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>       
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what I was trying to do above was show a list of all the apps with package name starting with `com.google.android` and its associated icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rectify this by inflating the right layout from the outset. `R.layout.widget_image` should already have whatever stuff you have in `R.layout.widget_image` and `R.layout.widget_item`.

This will be:

- faster to execute (fewer instructions to achieve same visual end)
- less Java code
- less layout code (one layout file versus three)
- easier to maintain layout code (you can use the visual editor in Eclipse to maintain your list rows better)

And, as an extra bonus, it should work for any supported `AdapterView`-based app widget.

Comment: Umm.. I dont think I understood it fully.. sorry, but this widget concept is a little hard for me to grasp. I have updated the question and added the layout code. Could you please tell me what changes I should make to the xml and the code?

Comment: @rohith: You have `widget_item.xml`, `widget_text.xml`, and `widget_image.xml` as three separate files. Combine those into one file (presumably still named `widget_item.xml`), holding your `LinearLayout`, your `TextView`, and your `ImageView`. Delete the other two layout files. Delete where you are referring to those other two files in your Java code.

Comment: But then how do I set the text and image in the respective views?

Comment: @rohith: With your existing code. Your `setTextViewText()` calls and such do not change.

Comment: I have updated the code above. If I use addView() and add `image` and `text`, the issue persists.. if I dont, then the contents of the `ListView` are empty.